# Maxima: check if expression is defined

Tags: maxima

I want to test wether certain expressions are deifned, without having the programm to be stoped.
For example, if have two matrices:
[image]

I know that the product (A*B) of these two is not well defined. So i would like to have maxima print out that this product is not defined without interrupting the evaluation of more expression that are to be tested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you are interested in the [`errcatch`](https://maxima.sourceforge.io/docs/manual/maxima_175.html#index-errcatch) function that evaluates expressions and returns the results if there are no errors but returns an empty list if some error occurred.

You'll have to do a bit more work to do what you want, but at least Maxima won't stop on an error.